# Flipping a Leaflet.js map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, range

There is a Leaflet.js map that the user cannot move with the mouse (it is necessary that there be only one map that does not move to another)

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    dragging: false,
    touchZoom: false,
    scrollWheelZoom: false, 
    doubleClickZoom: false, 
    boxZoom: false,
    maxBounds: L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(40, -10), L.latLng(60, 10)),
    maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0
}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 2);

var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});
osm.addTo(map);
```

You need to make an input of type range so that you can scroll through the map without going beyond the borders. I tried it myself but it does not work correctly (it does not scroll).

I leave the code of what I did myself. It can be useful

```
<section class="map-section">
  <div class="map-container">
     <div id="map"></div>
     <input type="range" id="horizontal-pan-slider" min="-50" max="50" step="1" value="0">
  </div>
</section>
```

```
var horizontalPanSlider = document.getElementById('horizontal-pan-slider');


horizontalPanSlider.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var horizontalPanValue = parseInt(horizontalPanSlider.value);
  var mapBounds = map.getBounds();
  var horizontalOffset = (mapBounds.getEast() - mapBounds.getWest()) * horizontalPanValue / 100;
  map.panBy([horizontalOffset, 0], { animate: false });
});
```

Comment: It is better to make your question a question, and answer it yourself in answer area. On that way, you can achieve upvotes from both parts, and people know that where to search for the answer.